# setting ServerName with Augeas

Tags: httpd.conf, puppet-enterprise, augeas

I am trying to use a Augeas resource to set the `ServerName` in my `httpd.conf` like so ...

```
# configure Apache HTTP server
augeas { 'ServerName':
    context => '/files/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf',
    changes => "set ServerName ${controller_name}",
} ->
```

... but I get this error:

```
[Debug: Augeas[ServerName](provider=augeas): Opening augeas with root /, lens path , flags 32^[[0m
[Debug: Augeas[ServerName](provider=augeas): Augeas version 1.2.0 is installed^[[0m
[Debug: Augeas[ServerName](provider=augeas): Will attempt to save and only run if files changed^[[0m
[Debug: Augeas[ServerName](provider=augeas): sending command 'set' with params ["/files/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf/ServerName", "svl-ost-centos.cisco.com"]^[[0m
[Debug: Augeas[ServerName](provider=augeas): Put failed on one or more files, output from /augeas//error:^[[0m
[Debug: Augeas[ServerName](provider=augeas): /augeas/files/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf/error = put_failed^[[0m
[Debug: Augeas[ServerName](provider=augeas): /augeas/files/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf/error/path = /files/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf^[[0m
[Debug: Augeas[ServerName](provider=augeas): /augeas/files/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf/error/lens = /opt/puppet/share/augeas/lenses/dist/httpd.aug:88.10-.44:^[[0m
[Debug: Augeas[ServerName](provider=augeas): /augeas/files/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf/error/message = Malformed child node 'ServerName'^[[0m
[Debug: Augeas[ServerName](provider=augeas): Closed the augeas connection^[[0m
[Error: /Stage[main]/Wrapcontroller/Augeas[ServerName]: Could not evaluate: Saving failed, see debug^[[0m
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Directives in the `Httpd.lns` lens are not node labels. Instead, the tree should look like this:

```
/directive = "ServerName"
/directive/arg = "${controller_name}"
```

The way to achieve that with Puppet is:

```
augeas { 'ServerName':
    context => '/files/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf',
    changes => [
      'set directive[.="ServerName"] "ServerName"',
      "set directive[.="ServerName"]/arg '${controller_name}'",
    ],
}
```